# Update square's iframe input tag value

Tags: square

The squareup paymentform library upon loading converts the designated input tags to be new input tags, each inside of an iframe. However these new input tags don't have an ID attribute.

Is there a way to update the value of the Credit Card Number, for example, through jquery?

Comment: Are you referring to auto-populating the fields? If so, then no that is not possible (except for the postal code). If you're referring to customizing the fields, take a look at this: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/setup#optional-customize-payment-form-styles

Comment: Not sure how I missed it in the docs but being able to populate the postal code is what I was looking for. Thanks.